# Travis-CI giving errors during commit

Tags: javascript, travis-ci, node-fibers, flow-based-programming

I have a JavaScript application called JSFBP - https://github.com/jpaulm/jsfbp - using node-fibers, which has started giving Travis errors - as of Oct. 25.  The log file is https://travis-ci.org/jpaulm/jsfbp/jobs/615992765 . Could a node-fibers person take a look, or point me at a more appropriate place to ask the question...?  TIA

Answer (score 0):

Turned out that node-fibers wasn't up-to-date - the latest version is 4.0.2 . Not sure why renovate didn't pick up on that, but at least Travis did!  Thanks anyway!